# Remove duplicate rows where col1 and col2 are equal but reversed

Tags: sql

I have a query that has the following results.  How can I modify this query to remove duplicate rows.  In this case, the duplicates would be "row1.antecedent = row2.consequent and row2.antecedent= row1.consequent".  I only need one such row, not both in my results.  Also, this logic has to be directly added in the query, not the encompassing programming language.

[Query Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAU5m.png)

So let's assume this my table with the data as shown.  I would like to select rows from this table such that only rows with rule_id = 943,945 and 979 are selected.  That's because 944 gives me same results as 943; 946 is same as 945 and 980 is same as 979, except with the antecedent and consequent reversed.  Please ignore the value CONF. That would be different.

| RULE_ID | ANTECEDENT | CONSEQUENT | SUPP | CONF | LIFT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 943 | 3017 | 3014 | 0.69% | 65.59% | 55.78 |
| 944 | 3014 | 3017 | 0.69% | 58.46% | 55.78 |
| 945 | 3018 | 3014 | 0.81% | 55.60% | 47.29 |
| 946 | 3014 | 3018 | 0.81% | 68.86% | 47.29 |
| 979 | 3055 | 3015 | 0.62% | 60.35% | 68.9 |
| 980 | 3015 | 3055 | 0.62% | 70.30% | 68.9 |

UPDATED QUERY - THIS WORKS

```
select * from (
SELECT 
RULE_ID,
A.ATTRIBUTE_SUBNAME ANTECEDENT,
C.ATTRIBUTE_SUBNAME CONSEQUENT,
CONCAT(TO_CHAR(RULE_SUPPORT*100,'990.99'),'%') Support_Frequency,
CONCAT(TO_CHAR(RULE_CONFIDENCE*100,'990.99'),'%') Confidence_Association,
ROUND(RULE_LIFT, 2) Lift_Likelyhood
FROM TABLE(DBMS_DATA_MINING.GET_ASSOCIATION_RULES('AR_SH_SAMPLE')) T,
TABLE(T.CONSEQUENT) C,
TABLE(T.ANTECEDENT) A
) where rule_id in 
(
select min(rule_id) from
(
SELECT 
RULE_ID,
A.ATTRIBUTE_SUBNAME ANTECEDENT,
C.ATTRIBUTE_SUBNAME CONSEQUENT,
CONCAT(TO_CHAR(RULE_SUPPORT*100,'990.99'),'%') Support_Frequency,
CONCAT(TO_CHAR(RULE_CONFIDENCE*100,'990.99'),'%') Confidence_Association,
ROUND(RULE_LIFT, 2) Lift_Likelyhood,
(CASE 
WHEN A.ATTRIBUTE_SUBNAME > C.ATTRIBUTE_SUBNAME THEN CONCAT(A.ATTRIBUTE_SUBNAME,C.ATTRIBUTE_SUBNAME)
WHEN C.ATTRIBUTE_SUBNAME > A.ATTRIBUTE_SUBNAME THEN CONCAT(C.ATTRIBUTE_SUBNAME,A.ATTRIBUTE_SUBNAME)
END) CAT
FROM TABLE(DBMS_DATA_MINING.GET_ASSOCIATION_RULES('AR_SH_SAMPLE')) T,
TABLE(T.CONSEQUENT) C,
TABLE(T.ANTECEDENT) A
)
group by CAT
)
ORDER BY RULE_ID
```

Comment: Without sample data, desired results, and the query you are using (perhaps simplified), it is really hard to understand your question.

Comment: The results are in the "Query Results" link that is directly below the question

Comment: Could you at least add these results as text, not as image?

Comment: This the the query, however it's not straight forward to explain since there are other stored procedures that are executed before this query.  SELECT 
RULE_ID,
A.ATTRIBUTE_SUBNAME ANTECEDENT,
C.ATTRIBUTE_SUBNAME CONSEQUENT,
CONCAT(TO_CHAR(RULE_SUPPORT*100,'990.99'),'%') Support_Frequency,
CONCAT(TO_CHAR(RULE_CONFIDENCE*100,'990.99'),'%') Confidence_Association,
ROUND(RULE_LIFT, 2) Lift_Likelyhood
FROM TABLE(DBMS_DATA_MINING.GET_ASSOCIATION_RULES('AR_SH_SAMPLE')) T,
TABLE(T.CONSEQUENT) C,
TABLE(T.ANTECEDENT) A
ORDER BY RULE_ID;

Comment: Sure, let me try to show results as text.  This is my first time on stack overflow, so thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need to treat some rows in your table as duplicates, GROUP BY is the way to go: the trick is to build up a GROUP BY expression so that `{ X, Y }` and `{ Y, X }` tuples are treated as the same value. Here's one possible approach:

```
GROUP BY IF(
  ANTECEDENT > CONSEQUENT, 
  CONCAT(ANTECEDENT, "+", CONSEQUENT), 
  CONCAT(CONSEQUENT, "+", ANTECEDENT) 
)
```

After that you can use this GROUP BY to fetch data the way you need (and it's not clear what exactly you need here, which of two rows should be excluded). Here's one way to show only the "first" rows of the duplicate sets:

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table
 WHERE rule_id IN (
    SELECT MIN(rule_id)
      FROM your_table
  GROUP BY IF(
             ANTECEDENT > CONSEQUENT, 
             CONCAT(ANTECEDENT, "+", CONSEQUENT), 
             CONCAT(CONSEQUENT, "+", ANTECEDENT) 
           )
       )
```

Comment: Thanks, that concat option worked, although I used CASE instead of IF.  I've included the updated query above.  The only problem  I see with my updated query is that, the query runs the Get_Association_Rules function twice which may not be very optimal, but I guess we can live with it for now

Comment: I see. As a general sidenote (as you're new to SO): if answer is helpful, consider accepting it (instead of adding it to the question's body itself). It helps others to recognize the problem AND the solution faster. Here's more [about it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: And yes, the query you added can be simplified (not sure it's worth it, may be performance is not that much of concern anyway) - but that deserves a separate question. BTW, I'm not sure why your original question was closed; after you added enough details (the query itself) it sounds like a relevant issue worth investigating. Will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions @raina77ow.  I've accepted your answer because it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

use `GROUP BY`

Example:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
GROUP BY column_name(s)
ORDER BY column_name(s);
```

or `SELECT DISTINCT` in your query.

Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name;
```